# How much is the cost of interrupt in x86_64

Tags: c, linux, x86-64

How much is the cost of interrupt in x86_64. For example the interrupt due to a page fault? How much cycles are required for the kernel to service the interrupt and then go back to user-space? I am interested in knowning only the cost due to the interrupt and scheduling the interrupted user-level thread back, so we can neglect what is going on inside the interrupt handler here.

Comment: This would be hardware dependent. As such, I'm not sure why GCC, C or Linux are tagged.

Comment: Hm ... Isn't it possible that this would involve paging in memory from swap, i.e. tens of milliseconds? If so, I don't understand how that part can be ignored, since letting the userspace code carry on before the memory contents are in place seems impossible.

Comment: u r right unwind, but at this moment I want to know the overhead only due to the interrupt and scheduling back of user-space interrupted thread. Assume, all pages are in RAM.

Answer (score 1):

For odrinary interrupts (hardware IRQ or ordinary exception like division by zero) it is probably possible to give an upper bound.

Time to process a page fault is especially tricky to assess even when disk IO is not involved because the CPU has to walk the page tables, which introduces many variables. Page faults occur not only because pages are not present, but also because of access violations (e.g., trying to write to a read-only page). In any case, if the page mapping is not already present in the TLB (missing mappings are never cached), the CPU will first have to walk multiple levels of page tables before even invoking the page fault handler.  The time to access page table entries (in case the address is not already cached in the TLB) is again dependent on whether some entries are already in data caches.

So the time from accessing a linear address to PF handler being invoked might be anything from ~200 cycles (best case; TLB entry present, exception due to wrong access type -- just ring switch) to ~2000 cycles (no TLB entry present, no page table entries in data cache). This is just the time between 1) executing a user-mode instruction that faults and 2) executing the first instruction of the page fault handler.

[Side-comment: given that, I wonder whether it's possible to build hard real-time systems that use paging.]

Answer (score 0):

This is a complex question and cannot be answered easily.

You have to save all (used) registers (scalar,sse,fpu-state,avx, etc.) that are being used in the interrupt.

Maybe you have to change the virtual address space context.

When you are done, you have to reset the saved context.

And all the while cache/RAM load effects change the cycle count needed.

(NB: Interrupts should not be paged out, but no idea if linux supports this, or if it is at all possible)

Comment: Kernels generally forbid use of anything but integer instructions. Also, they are also generally (Linux and Win, at least) mapped into the process's address space, only protected from access.

Comment: @zvrba: while kernels usually don't use floating point et al., you still have to save the state, usually lazy-save it (i.e. don't save it if the process hasn't used the FPU), since you can switch to another process that also uses the FPU/SSE/whatever...

Comment: @zvrba You are right, that a interrupt handler does not need to save all registers, but maybe e.g. SSE due to memcpy. And you are right, that under windows they are already mapped into the process address space, but I didn't know if this was the case in Linux. The point is still, that you have to rescue some registers. You have to have certain things mapped in memory, but those should not be the 'heavy weight' things, due to caching effects, which are generally hard to quantify.

Comment: @ninjalj Kernels do have to save all 'thread' state when switching threads, but an interrupt is not a thread. It cannot be interrupted by a lower priority thread, so you do not have to save things you do not need in the interrupt, because it is guaranteed that you either are interrupted by a higher(/same) priority interrupt or you return normally from it and can restore the saved state.